# k8s ingress setup - invalid type for io.k8s.api.networking.v1.ServiceBackendPort.number: got "string", expected

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I'm trying to setup an ingress in kubernetes for my frontend, the code is as below.

```
datahub-frontend:
  enabled: true
  image:
    repository: linkedin/datahub-frontend-react
    tag: "v0.8.31"
  ingress:
    enabled: true
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: alb
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/scheme: internet-facing
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/target-type: instance
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:ap-southeast-2:601628467906:certificate/xxxxxxxxxxxxx
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/inbound-cidrs: 0.0.0.0/0
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
      alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.ssl-redirect: '{"Type": "redirect", "RedirectConfig": { "Protocol": "HTTPS", "Port": "443", "StatusCode": "HTTP_301"}}'
    hosts:
      - host: xxxxx.com
        redirectPaths:
          - path: /*
            name: ssl-redirect
            port: use-annotation
        paths:
          - /*
```

This is giving me the following error.

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend.service.port.number): invalid type for io.k8s.api.networking.v1.ServiceBackendPort.number: got "string", expected "integer"
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps as your manifest seems to be missing 'spec' and 'rules'?. But I got the same error when I accidentally used 'backend.service.port.number'. This error was fixed when I used 'backend.service.port.name'.

Answer (score 0):

seems like the ingress definition you posted is incorrect. It is missing the required `spec` and `rules` according to [kubernetes doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#the-ingress-resource).

This contains an [example ingress for ssl-redirect](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.4/guide/tasks/ssl_redirect/)

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: ingress
  annotations:
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/certificate-arn: arn:aws:acm:us-west-2:xxxx:certificate/xxxxxx
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/listen-ports: '[{"HTTP": 80}, {"HTTPS":443}]'
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: '443'
spec:
  ingressClassName: alb
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
         - path: /users/*
           pathType: ImplementationSpecific
           backend:
             service:
               name: user-service
               port:
                 number: 80
         - path: /*
           pathType: ImplementationSpecific
           backend:
             service:
               name: default-service
               port:
                 number: 80
```

I see that you are using `actions` annotation, you need to specify `Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend.service.port.name` with `use-annotation`. Make sure `Ingress.spec.rules[0].http.paths[0].backend.service.port.number` is not used.

```yaml
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    ...
    ...
    alb.ingress.kubernetes.io/actions.my-rule: '{"type":"fixed-response","fixedResponseConfig":{"contentType":"text/plain","statusCode":"200","messageBody":"hello world"}}'
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /*
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-rule
            port:
              name: use-annotation
```